PowerShell, Create a separate Parent process that will not die when the creating process dies
This question has been asked here, but I do not find any workable solution there (it is pointed out in comments below that Start-Process powershell.exe does create an independent process so that I am probably wrong in thinking that this dies with the parent).
Outside of PowerShell, there is also this question, but again, no answer is shown, just a hypothetical discussion of what might work.
I very much want to be able to start some PowerShell code, ProcessB, as a background process, that is started by a PowerShell script running in ProcessA, such that if ProcessA is terminated (e.g. the ProcessA console window is closed), then ProcessB will continue to run in the background as its own parent process independent of ProcessA.
The two possible methods from the first question above are:
Invoke-WmiMethod -Class Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList ScriptA.ps1

or this:
Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -AsJob -ScriptBlock { sleep 10; cmd /c set > c:\env.txt; }

But so far I have been unable to get either to work (a ScriptBlock that works fine under Start-Job fails to work with the Invoke-Command -AsJob method above, and also, it treats the process as if it's running on a remote system, requiring remoting requirements I believe, or at least this is alluded to in the answer).
How can we spawn a process from a PowerShell script that is not a child process of the creating script, but is its own independent parent process?

What exactly happens when you do Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-File","ScriptA.ps1"? Your assertion that "it dies" when the parent process does is simply not true

Well, I might be wrong, but I thought that Start-Process always created a child process of the creating process. You use this regularly? I'll go and test some more, thanks.

Try start-job : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-7.4

This is partly why I asked this question, as in my testing, Start-Job fails in this respect. @Mathias R. Jessen is right and in fact, I now do not see any situation in which Start-Job is actually the right choice (for anything). Start-Process can start a child process, or an independent parent process, while Start-Job looks like it should be the right tool to use, but in fact fails at this task (from my testing anyway). If you can show Start-Job creating a separate independent parent process that persists after closing the creating process, I would appreciate seeing that.
